# How to attach AsYouType() (libphonenumber-js) to a reactive Angular ion-input field?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic-input field to take a phone number. It performs the formatting, but after the user enters the area code & then tries to backspace one of the parenthesis, it will just infinitely keep adding them because it is replacing the input on each keychange.

In the libphonenumber-js demo, it has a field which does format it properly and allow for normal backspacing. So my conclusion is that I have attached the AsYouType object improperly to the field.

So how do I attach this properly to my reactive Angular form using ion-input?

TS Form group declaration:

```js
 demographicsForm = new FormGroup({
    phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
```

TS OnPhoneChange():

```js
onPhoneChange() { //format phone number as user types. 
    if (this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value ) {
        let formattedTel = new AsYouType('US').input(this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value);
        const phoneControl = this.demographicsForm.get('phone');
        phoneControl.setValue(formattedTel);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Phone *</ion-label>
    <ion-input (ionChange)="onPhoneChange()" formControlName="phone" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will not mark this as the solution because it is not elegant and I do not believe uses the best design. However, this is my temporary workaround.

It detects what length the phone number is based on the auto formatting (ie. (555) is five characters, (555) 555 is nine characters including the space) and then either formats or skips formatting.

```js
onPhoneChange() { 
    if (this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value && this.phoneParenthesis == false) {
        let formattedTel = new AsYouType('US').input(this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value);
        const phoneControl = this.demographicsForm.get('phone');
        phoneControl.setValue(formattedTel); 
        this.phoneParenthesis = true; 
    }
    if(this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value.length >= 6){
        let formattedTel = new AsYouType('US').input(this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value);
        const phoneControl = this.demographicsForm.get('phone');
        phoneControl.setValue(formattedTel);
    }
    if(this.demographicsForm.get('phone').value.length < 3){
        this.phoneParenthesis = false;
    }
}
```